# Concern with using external SQL server for DIH

Tags: sql, search, solr, lucene

I am looking to import entries to my SOLR server by using the DIH, connecting to an external PostgreSQL server using the JDBC driver. I will be importing about 50,000 entries each time.

Is connecting to an external SQL server for my data unreliable or risky, or is it instead perfectly reasonable?

My only alternative is to export the SQL file on the other server, download the SQL file to my SOLR server, import it to my Solr servers copy of PostgreSQL and then run the DIH on the local database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're using it is pretty much why the DIH exists.  Otherwise, you could just use the `/update` handler with XML documents. The core I'm working on right now regularly indexes 11,000,000 rows per batch.

Comment: Yes, with a remote SQL server.  So long as your Solr server can connect to it via that JDBC connection, you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard use case, importing from a remote DB.  Proceed with confidence!

Comment: When you say importing do you mean doing a remote query or importing the entire DB to the same server as the solr

Comment: I mean querying the remote DB